# Using Grunt to generate HTML files inside directories

Tags: html, node.js, email, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm using to [grunt-compile-handlebars](https://github.com/patrickkettner/grunt-compile-handlebars) part of an email build.

I need to create different color variants of the same template, giving each compiled HTML file an appropriate name and inside a named directory.

For example the text will be a different color in each.

So an example result may be:

```
|-red
  |-red-template.html
|-green
  |-green-template.html
|-blue
  |-blue-template.html
```

I can do this manually, but automation would be better. It doesn't look like grunt-compile-handlebars has the capability.

Are there any Grunt plugins that are able to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-file-creator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a static site generator like [Assemble.io](http://assemble.io/).  It breaks parts of your templates into partials, and you can use different colored partials for different templates.